# Minhag not to eat ANY lamb at seder night?

Tags: minhag, passover, eating, meat, evening-night

I seem to recall an Ashkenazi minhag not to eat any form of lamb on seder night. I don't mean the widely spread custom not to eat a roasted lamb, but even , for example, braised lamb shanks.

Is this indeed a widespread minhag among ashkenazim? Which communities practise it?

Comment: I do not eat lamb at seder night, in the same way I do not eat any roasted meat. Both for the same reason. We do have a lamb bone on the table.

Comment: @CashCow, I don't eat any lamb, either, in the same way I don't eat venison or okra. But the question was whether this is a widespread _minhag_ and among which communities.

Comment: I'm really trying to suss out if this is legit, or if it's some modern-age humra that people keep without really knowing where it comes from.

Comment: @benny if its your family's tradition, then it's legit for you.

Comment: It's hard to say that I certainly have a tradition to not do something. No one ever got up and said "hey everyone, we're not eating lamb tonight". I would know if it was certainly the case that this was my minhag, but I don't, so I'm asking: is this something people stam do, or did it grow out of the minhag not to have roasted without any specific reason asides from chumra creep.

Comment: I recall an Aruch Hashulchan that assumes the minhag is basically an extension of the roasted lamb custom and then argues that (e.g.) baked lamb would be sufficiently removed that it should be permitted.

Comment: @Nic I'd love to see that inside, do you have a maremakom?

Comment: It's not quite what I remembered, but look here:https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%95

Comment: Though I'm Ashkenazi, this certainly isn't my minhag. Sure, we don't roast it, but we do eat it.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Passover) says:

> Today, in the absence of the Temple, the mitzvah of the Korban Pesach
>   is memorialized in the form of a symbolic food placed on the Passover
>   Seder Plate, which is usually a roasted shankbone. Ashkenazic Jews
>   have a custom of not eating lamb or goat during the Seder in deference
>   to the absence of the Temple. Many Sephardic Jews, however, have the
>   opposite custom of eating lamb or goat meat during the Seder in memory
>   of the Korban Pesach.

It seems to be a widespread custom among Ahskenazim not eat any lamb in any form. I don't know of any Ashkenazy who does otherwise.

IMO, this is not a chumra, but rather there seems to be some basis to the thinking. It seems to be the same reasoning why I have seen many Hagaddah instructions state not to point to a roasted lamb shank on the Seder plate while saying "Pesach zeh".

Comment: Can you back up your claim that it's but a chumra with something other than an English online encyclopedia and your gut feeling?

Comment: @BennyPowers If I locate something else, I'll try to post it. Re "chumra" - there are numerous chumrot that people perform. Some have sensible reasons, some make no sense, and some have no reason at all.